# What is a good design pattern to build complex objects from complex database function?

Tags: design-patterns, data-access-layer

I have a complex structure that needs to be built using data read from database, and I need to know where to place my database access logic.

I read about Repository design pattern, but my database operations are not simple CRUD, and they are not just returning simple values.

I am connecting to PostgreSQL and calling functions that often return data as a set of cursors.

Here is a very simplified part of my code... I have omitted some details

```
class Topic
{
    public string TopicLabel { get; set; }

    public int TopicCode { get; set; }

    List<Topic> parentTopics;

    public Topic(int topicCode , string topicLabel)
    {
        ...
    }

}       


class InitialTopic
{
    Topic initialTopic;

    public int TopicCode { get { return initialTopic.TopicCode; } }            
    Dictionary<int, float> similarityValues;

    public InitialTopic( Topic topic)
    {
        initialTopic = topic;
        similarityValues = new Dictionary<int, float>();
    }

}



class TopicsDictionary
{
    Dictionary<int, Topic> topics;

    public TopicsDictionary()
    {
        topics = new Dictionary<int, Topic>();
    }     

    public Topic this[int topicCode]
    {
        get
        {
            Topic t = null;
            if (topics.ContainsKey(topicCode))
            {
                t = topics[topicCode];                    
            }
            else
            {
                t = new Topic(topicCode);
                topics.Add(topicCode, t);
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
}

     .
     .
     .  

public static void GetData(InitialTopic initialTopic)
{

     using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("public.\"GetStuff\"", conn);
        .
        .

        string cursor1, cursor2;
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dr.Read();
            cursor1 = dr[0].ToString();
            dr.Read();
            cursor2 = dr[0].ToString();
        }                   

        using (var resultSet1 = new NpgsqlCommand())
        {
            resultSet1.CommandText = $@"FETCH ALL FROM ""{cursor1}""";
            resultSet1.Connection = conn;

            using (var reader = resultSet1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // here read values, create Topic objects,
                // add them to TopicsDictionary and link them using parentTopics list 
                // to reflect parent-child relation
            }
        }           

        using (var resultSet2 = new NpgsqlCommand())
        {
            resultSet2.CommandText = $@"FETCH ALL FROM ""{cursor2}""";
            resultSet2.Connection = conn;

            using (var reader = resultSet2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // here read values and fill similarityValues 
                // dictionary in InitialTopic object
            }
        }

        tran.Commit();
        conn.Close();

    }
}
```

Should I separate database operation from the actual building of objects (topic objects and their member lists and dictionaries) ? How should I do that? Is there an appropriate design pattern for such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I separate database operation from the actual building of objects (topic objects and their member lists and dictionaries) ?

Definately yes. Your two code blocks inside `using (var reader =` are complicated enough so that (1) your `GetData` method looks ugly, (2) you want to do unit tests for those code, and (3) you want to reuse those code when switching to another database system e.g., MySQL.

> How should I do that? Is there an appropriate design pattern for such case?

Just extract the two code blocks out of the `GetData` method to somewhere else. Since your `InitialTopic` class is pretty clean, you can move to here. But it’s up to you.

Now the only challenge is that how the `InitialTopic` class receives data from the two readers. Sure, we will pass the readers to the `initialTopic` object. But we should not let the `InitialTopic` class depend on a database class (the type of your readers).

Normally to solve this we apply the Dependency Inversion Principle. A new interface is introduced for abstracting the readers’ operations:

```
interface MyReader {
    // hasNext() and next() methods, right?
}
```

We will let the `InitialTopic` class depend on `MyReader` interface.

Now we write an adapter to adapt the Npgsql readers (the readers in `using (var reader =`):

```
class MyNpgsqlReader : MyReader {
    // use Dependency Injection to inject the Npgsql reader
}
```

Finally, the two code blocks in the `GetData` method become:

```
using (var reader = resultSet1.ExecuteReader()) {
    initialTopic.method1(new MyNpgsqlReader(reader));
}
...
using (var reader = resultSet2.ExecuteReader()) {
    initialTopic.method2(new MyNpgsqlReader(reader));
}
```

Comment: So, GetData will still have initialTopic as an input argument, but it will pass its readers to initialTopic to do whatever it needs with retrieved data. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What about GetData? should it be in a separate class dedicated for database operations? or could it just be a method member within a parent class that has objects of smaller classes (InitialTopic, Topic...etc) ?

Comment: Should be the first option. Database operations (Npgsql, Mysql ...) and business operations (InitialTopic, Topic ...) should not be mixed together.